# Error: Could not create connection to databases server

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jdbc

I am developing an Android App in Kotlin (Android Studio) Please help me out with this error.

1. The Internet permission is already added in the AndroidMenifest.xml
2. My MySql server is hosted on Hostinger Server and the permission is already granted.
3. the username, password, and Database name are correct.

It gives the error called:
`Error: Cloud not create connection to databases server.`

This is The code

```
package com.pack.app

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Message
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.Statement
import java.sql.SQLException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var user_id: EditText
    private lateinit var password: EditText
    private lateinit var login_btn: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        supportActionBar?.hide()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        user_id = findViewById(R.id.user_id)
        password = findViewById(R.id.password)
        login_btn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn)

        login_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val user_id = user_id.text.toString()
            val password = password.text.toString()

            if(user_id.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()){
                try {
                    val url = "jdbc:mysql://sql.mydoman.com/dbname"
                    val user = "username"
                    val dbpassword = "dbPassword"

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    val conn: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, dbpassword)

                    val query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"
                    val pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)
                    pstmt.setString(1, user_id)
                    pstmt.setString(2, password)
                    val resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery()


                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                        // Login successful
                        showToast("Login successful")
                    } else {
                        // Login failed
                        showToast("Invalid credentials")
                    }

                    resultSet.close()
                    pstmt.close()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        showToast("Error: " + e.message)

                }
            }else{
                showToast("Please enter correct user id & password")
            }


        }
    }
    private fun showToast(message: String){
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the entire exception stacktrace, not just the exception message. That said, you shouldn't connect to a database server directly from Android. Use a REST API to mediate between your Android app and the database.

Comment: I’m not sure, but I think you should add the port to your connection url: `val url = "jdbc:mysql://sql.mydoman.com:your_port/dbname"`

Comment: Never use jdbc in an Android app.  Putting the password to your db into an apk is totally insecure.

Comment: @PatrickCumpa Without a port, the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver will default to port 3306 (the default MySQL port).